# What are people doing for login security on web applications?

Tags: security, spring, eclipselink

I am using Eclipselink, Spring and an Oracle database. How should I configure security and the database connection?

I am looking for tutorials/articles that would address this or at least give me a direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're already using Spring, Spring Security.

The [Spring Security Getting Started Guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/start-here.html) is a good place to start, and there are a [number of tutorials](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-security-tutorials/) available, like [this one](http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-mvc-integration.html).

Comment: Here is what I understand. To use the application/database connection the user needs to be authenticated via Spring Security, right? Then once authenticated the database connection made via gatekeeper account allows access to the database.

Comment: @Miller I'm not sure what you mean by gatekeeper account, but how spring security works is very configurable. You can protect whatever resources you want in a variety of ways.

Comment: The gatekeeper is the application's credentials to the database.

Comment: @Miller Normally a web app will have a single DB user and all DB access happens through it. How authentication occurs is completely configurable, it *could* use the DB, but does not *need* to, it could be hardcover, LFAP, anything. But yes, normally the app user wouldn't have access tom restricted site areas and/or data until they've been authenticated and authorized.

Comment: Thx that makes sense. I think that I was looking at it the wrong way. Security is designed to protect the application resources including the database connection. And, the authentication was a completely separate process.

Comment: @miller Ugh, autocomplete. I meant "hard-coded", not hardcover, and LDAP, not... LFAP?! I don't even want to know how *that* one got in there. But yep, the DB connection is almost always handled internally.

Answer (score 0):

AppFuse is a good start: http://appfuse.org/display/APF/AppFuse+QuickStart

It uses Spring security and out of the box uses MySQL but changing it to use Oracle should be quite simple.